# Organize shows and episodes

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'm moving from years after using joomla to drupal and i've hit the learning curve.

My question is below.

I want to create content like this:

```
Many shows
Each show has many episodes
Each show has many tags (genres)

Shows should be listable
Episodes should be listable per show
Shows should be listable per genre
```

It's basically a database for tv shows. But I want to hit the ground running.

I'm currently stuck with taxonomy and content types. Would a show and episode each be a content type? How can I relate them to each other?

I'm running drupal 7.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like two content types: `Show` and `Episode`. You'll want to look into the [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to relate episodes to shows. This adds an `Entity reference` field type. And you'll be using `Term reference` fields for tagging.

Comment: sweet thanks! That's exactly what I needed to know!